# ExtJS Modern getting and showing hidden node in tree view

Tags: extjs, extjs7

I'm having issues getting the node and record. Also I can not make a node that is `visible: false` on init to show programmatically.

Check out this fiddle
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3hs5

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. I used `setData` instead of `root.appendChild` so the store wasn't correctly populated.

The fiddle is updated and now works